# Embedding OpenOffice application in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to embed OpenOffice Impress into my WPF application (C#). Please can someone please guide me on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: what did you try so far? how are you trying to embedd it?

Comment: I've not tried writing any code yet, just researching on the web for suggestions on how to go about it. Basically I'm writing a C# application to auto generate a presentation based on database information using OO API. After the bulk of the presentation is generated, I would want to allow the user to further customize the slides, by having the openoffice impress program launched and embedded in my application.